# ios retrieve when uitabbarcontroller item is selected

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to retrieve when a user click over a tabbaritem into a uitabbarcontroller to change something..
here is my code:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if (item == [tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2]) {
        item.title = @"add shot";
    }
    else
    {
        item.title = @"Race";
    }
}
```

but If I do this:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.delegate = self;
```

i receive a sigkill...

what's the right solution? thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your view controller conform to the UITabBarDelegate protocol?
In the header file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate> {
    // ...
}

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;

@end
```

Then, just do:

```
tabBar.delegate = self;
```

Instead of:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.delegate = self;
```

And:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    //self.tabBarItem.title = @"Title";
}
```

Comment: with tabBarController.delegate doesn't give me sigkill, but the didSelectItem method is of the UITabBarDelegate, not UITabBarControllerDelegate

Comment: Updated answer, try that out.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this answer while learning iOS development, But I wanted to include the little missing pieces for n00bs like me.

```
// HelloWorldViewController.h
@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate>
{   
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;    
@end
```

And

```
// HelloWorldViewController.m
@interface HelloWorldViewController ()

@end

@implementation HelloWorldViewController 
@synthesize tabBar;
- (void) viewDidLoad
{ 
   tabBar.delegate = self;
}

-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
      NSLog(@"didSelectItem: %d", item.tag);
}

@end
```

Comment: BRAVO! You made my day! Great piece of code thats works for me!